# Difference between typedef in C and application-defined types in Ada

Tags: c, types, typedef, ada

So I was learning about application-defined types in Ada and it seems like `typedef` in C programming language. However, if I created a new name for a predefined type in C using typedef I can still do this:

```
typedef int my_int;
int a = 5;
my_int b = a; -- No problem
```

But if I try this on Ada:

```
type my_int is new Integer;
a : Integer := 5;
b : my_int  := a; -- Causes some error
```

So my question is that is my understanding correct that in C `my_int` is just an alias or a new name of type `int` and not a new type whereas in Ada `my_int` is a completely different data type itself not just a new name for type `Integer`.

Comment: There's even a literally same example on the wiki: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Derived_types

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `subtype my_int is Integer;` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first, declaring type in Ada isn't that same as `typedef` in C. `typedef` is more like creating an alias of an existing simple type. The proper way in Ada to do this is to declare a type as *subtype*. In your example it should be (as Zerte suggested in comments):

```
subtype my_int is Integer;
```

In that situation your code will work. Side note: creating records in Ada is very similar to creating structures in C with `typedef`.

Ada is **a very** strongly typed language. A type can't be assigned to another type without a type conversion (called a "cast" in C-family languages). For example:

```
type My_Int is new Integer;
type My_Int2 is new Integer;
```

Both types are incompatible with each other or with their parent type Integer, and if you want to mix them, you have to use type conversions.

As someone who travelled from C to Ada land I think, the most important if you want to understand Ada, is to understand Ada types system. It is something completely different from C. C is more focused on manipulating data when Ada puts more emphasis on data representation.

Comment: Here is my favorite one. In C approximately 20% is statically checked while 80% is dynamically checked. In Ada, approximately 80% is statically checked while 20% is dynamically checked.

Comment: @AnhVo: I agree with that. :)

Answer (score 2):

> that is my understanding correct that in C my_int is just an alias or a new name of type int and not a new type whereas in Ada my_int is a completely different data type itself not just a new name for type Integer.

Very vague kind of, but if it's a new type or not has nothing to do with it - in C you can also do `char c = 1.123L;` with no problems. The difference is that C language has *implicit* conversion in this context - while Ada does not. Overall, these are different languages.